# RHEL Session Crash after simple terminal commands (eg. cd ~)

Tags: session, crash, redhat, rhel, xorg

I have currently problems, that my session crushes during simple terminal commands on my RHEL 6.4 machine with GNOME 2.28.2.

For example it will crush from time to time after executing `cd` commands. However it is not reproducable as sometimes the command executes as expected. Furthermore I can work for hours with rather complex programs like eclipse without having to fear a session crash. By now it only happens when using the terminal.

When it failes my session ends and the login screen appears. Therefore I guess the failure has something to do with my X Server. Here are the last lines of my Xorg.0.log.old:

```
[  3714.076] AUDIT: Mon Jul 15 08:53:35 2013: 18745: client 39 disconnected
[  3724.669] AUDIT: Mon Jul 15 08:53:45 2013: 18745: client 36 disconnected
[  3764.482] (EE) 
[  3764.482] (EE) Backtrace:
[  3764.483] (EE) 0: /usr/bin/Xorg (xorg_backtrace+0x36) [0x46cd76]
[  3764.483] (EE) 1: /usr/bin/Xorg (0x400000+0x72ad9) [0x472ad9]
[  3764.483] (EE) 2: /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x34fa600000+0xf500) [0x34fa60f500]
[  3764.483] (EE) 3: /lib64/libc.so.6 (__select+0x13) [0x34fa2e14d3]
[  3764.484] (EE) 4: /usr/bin/Xorg (WaitForSomething+0x1d2) [0x46a4d2]
[  3764.484] (EE) 5: /usr/bin/Xorg (0x400000+0x379d2) [0x4379d2]
[  3764.484] (EE) 6: /usr/bin/Xorg (0x400000+0x7cbca) [0x47cbca]
[  3764.484] (EE) 7: /lib64/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xfd) [0x34fa21ecdd]
[  3764.484] (EE) 8: /usr/bin/Xorg (0x400000+0x260b9) [0x4260b9]
[  3764.484] (EE) 
[  3764.484] 
Fatal server error:
[  3764.485] Caught signal 3 (Quit). Server aborting
[  3764.485] 
[  3764.485] (EE) 
Please consult the Red Hat, Inc. support 
     at https://www.redhat.com/apps/support/
 for help. 
[  3764.485] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[  3764.485] (EE) 
[  3764.506] (II) evdev: USB Optical Mouse: Close
[  3764.506] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  3764.514] (II) evdev: Razer Razer Lycosa: Close
[  3764.514] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  3764.521] (II) evdev: Razer Razer Lycosa: Close
[  3764.521] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  3764.529] (II) evdev: ThinkPad Extra Buttons: Close
[  3764.529] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  3764.537] (II) evdev: Lid Switch: Close
[  3764.537] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  3764.545] (II) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Close
[  3764.545] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  3764.553] (II) evdev: Sleep Button: Close
[  3764.553] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  3764.561] (II) evdev: Video Bus: Close
[  3764.561] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  3764.569] (II) evdev: Power Button: Close
[  3764.569] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  3764.586] (II) evdev: TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint: Close
[  3764.586] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  3764.602] (II) evdev: Macintosh mouse button emulation: Close
[  3764.602] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[  3764.634] (II) UnloadModule: "synaptics"
[  3764.635] (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
[  3764.748] Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

For a full record please feel free to visit: http://pastebin.com/2WN1Q6RR

Can you please help me with this annoying problem?

Edit:When the session dies a error message is displayed for a very short time. I now managed to get the error text:
`Exception: FMM9328E An error occured in the secure communication layer when running the following function: gsk_secure_soc_init(). GSKit returned code 486`
But I cound't find a solution regarding this error. Especially because I wonder how a socket initialitation can kill a whole session.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this problem and it looks like its related to a specific issue between IBM DB2 LUW version 10.1 and upstart-0.6.5-12.el6_4.1.

There is a RedHat errata / tech-note out with the title "If the db2 10.1 DAS service is running, an update to upstart causes the X server to crash, after pressing keys in a terminal in RHEL 6.4" (Updated July 25 2013 at 11:18 PM)

From the article:

Workaround #1:

Stop the DAS service using "/opt/ibm/db2/V10.1/bin/dasdrop system", this will require a reboot to take effect.

Workaround #2: 
Downgrade upstart. The newer version of upstart-0.6.5-12.el6_4.1 seems to have an unknown incompatability with db2-10 DAS service. It is recommended to downgrade to the prior version of upstart-0.6.5-12.el6 - Use yum to downgrade upstart: "yum downgrade upstart"

Root Cause: The root cause is unknown at this time. This is still being investigated and verified.